# Defeasible reasoning

Tags: logic, deduction, abduction

a. If x is a weekday, Xena goes to work on day x.
b. If Xena is ill, she doesn’t go to work that day.
c.2 Jan ‘07 was a weekday.
d. Xena was ill on 2 Jan. '07.
e. By (a) and (c), Xena went to work on 2 Jan ‘07.
f. By (b) and (d), Xena didn’t go to work on 2 Jan ‘07.
**g. By (e) and (f), Xena went to work and didn’t go to work on 2 Jan ‘07.**

Could some one explain me the defeasible reasoning and how is it related/different to deductive and abductive reasoning

Comment: It seems that you have a set of inconsistent premises, because the conclusion is a contradiction.

Comment: "It usually occurs when a rule is given, but there may be specific exceptions to the rule, or subclasses that are subject to a different rule", see [Defeasible reasoning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Defeasible_reasoning). Your a. states the "typical" rule, and your b. (without spelling that out) the exception that *overrides* it when applicable. The reason this is called "defeasible" is that if you do not have extra information from d. (called *defeater*), which activates the exception, you are justified to believe that Xena went to work. This conclusion is *defeated* when d. becomes known.

Comment: @Conifold Could you write an answer elaborating your comment and explaining how to incorporate b is stronger than a